# Question about definition of cardinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

In *Elements of Set Theory* by Enderton he defines the cardinal number of $A$ to be the least ordinal equinumerous to $A$.

Just before this definition is the Numeration Theorem which states that any set is equinumerous to some ordinal number. **My issue is that no justification is given for the existence of a *least* ordinal number equinumerous to $A$**, so I tried to justify it myself:

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal equinumerous to $A$. Then the set $\{\beta\in\alpha^+:\beta \text{ is equinumerous to $A$}\}$ is a nonempty set of ordinals, and hence has a least element $l$. Then $l$ is the least ordinal equinumerous to $A$.

Does this justification seem OK?

Comment: Yes, that works. In general, any nonempty class of ordinals contains a least element.

Comment: Surely Enderton has proved that the ordinals are well-ordered (by $\in$).  I'm not sure what is and isn't proven when he gives that definition of $|A|$. 

Your justification is almost right, but I have a quibble: what is $\alpha^+$? The cardinal successor of $|\alpha|$? — that is, the least ordinal not equinumerous with $|\alpha|$? It seems you're back to square one, having to justify the existence of such an ordinal.

Comment: @BrianO $a^+$ is $a\cup\{a\}$ for any set $a$.

Comment: @Hayden It's proven that any nonempty set of ordinals has a least element, but in his book a class is an informal thing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I have no quibble, and your justification is fine.

Comment: @lilypad I see, then you're right to be cautious. If you do happen to make the notion of a class precise in some fashion, you can use your approach to show the more general result.